# How to Push Azure analysis service model to azure devops git repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, ssas-tabular

I am using visual studio 2017 for azure analysis service model development. I am able to connect my git repo using team services but the sync is not working. As you can see the push to repo is greyed out. Any help on this will be great. 
Connected to git repo from visual studio 2017.
[image: here]

Comment: Any errorlogs to share?

Comment: @ZF007:Kindly find the screenshot link in the original post.you can see the push has been disabled.

Comment: Please add some more info of what you tried to solve it so far and if possible why it failed.

Comment: Do you have any local repo commits?  I would think Push is not available because "There are no outgoing commits."